# OpenVPN - ping OK but no web browser working on college

Tags: networking, ubuntu, openvpn

I used to protect myself using a VPN anywhere I connect my laptop. 
But in the college where I am, I can connect to the VPN via openVPN, I can ping google, I can even use torrent, but no internet working, in any web browser. Ubuntu apt install doesn't work neither.

I am currently with IpVanish provider, but I had the same issue last year with an other provider. I mention that the VPN works fine at home, I have this issue only at the college.

You can find the .opvn conf at : 
http://www.ipvanish.com/software/configs/

Here is one server :

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote syd-a02.ipvanish.com 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
persist-remote-ip
ca ca.ipvanish.com.crt
tls-remote syd-a02.ipvanish.com
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
verb 3
auth SHA256
cipher AES-256-CBC
keysize 256
tls-cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AES256-SHA
```

Here are the outputs from `ip route` when I am connected through the vpn at the college :

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 172.20.32.1 dev tun0 
default via 149.153.104.254 dev eth0  proto static 
128.0.0.0/1 via 172.20.32.1 dev tun0 
149.153.104.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 149.153.104.93  metric 1 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.42.1 
172.20.32.0/22 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.20.34.65 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1 
217.115.127.76 via 149.153.104.254 dev eth0
```

I am not a sys admin, and my knowledge is not too much advanced in networking, I did research but found nothing explicit. so thanks in advance

Comment: Try adding `fragment 1350` and `mssfix 1300` to your OpenVPN config file.

Comment: Testing with ping and torrent is not a very good test ..please add your client log to the question to show the connection to ipvanish